# Compute the integral involving a bounded measurable function.

Tags: integration, limits, measure-theory

Let $g$ be a bounded measurable function on $[a, b]$. Then compute the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b \frac{g(x)e^{nx}}{1+e^{nx}} dx$$

I write the given integral as
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b \frac{g(x)e^{nx}}{1+e^{nx}} dx = \int_a^b g(x) dx - \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b \frac{g(x)}{1+e^{nx}} dx$$ and i guess $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b \frac{g(x)}{1+e^{nx}} dx  = 0$$
Am i correct? How to prove the guess?

Comment: What limit theorems do you know?  For doing a limit under the integral?  Can you show that one of them applies in this case?

Comment: I know monotone convergence, Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem

Comment: ... and will one or more of these by applicable in this case?

Comment: I think Lebesgue dominated theorem is applicable. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes.  But note that the limit is different, depending on whether $x$ is positive or negative.

Comment: Exactly. So i need to make three cases then i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Lebesgue dominated convergence here since we can dominate the function inside the integral. Since $g(x)$ is bounded, there exists a constant $c$ s.t. $|g(x)|<c$. We also have that $1+e^{nx} > 1$, so we can combine these to get that the function inside the integral is dominated by a constant function,
$$\frac{|g(x)|}{1+e^{nx}} < c$$
This allows us to swap the limit and the integral, so now it comes down to evaluating 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{1+e^{nx}}\right) = \begin{cases}
0 & nx>0\\
\frac{1}{2} & nx=0\\
1 & nx<0
\end{cases}$$
These cases are all fairly straightforward, though you'll have to be careful when the sign of $nx$ swaps, so when $a$ is negative and $b$ is positive for example.